# VBA Count Rows and Return Value to to File

Tags: excel, vba, row, counter

I would like to count the number of rows in an excel file using vba and return that number not in a MsgBox but in the row after the last row the script initially counted.  So for Ex.  20 rows were detected return 21 in row 21 Column A.  I'm new to excel vba and have found a lot of links to return counter to MSGBox, I just want to return the same number to the same file it is counting

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
Dim i as Variant
i = 1
while Cells(i,1)<>""
    i=i+1
Wend
Cells(i,1) = i
```

(This assumes column A will always have data and the first time it finds a blank, it will assume it is the last row)

If that assumption doesn't hold:

You can also detect the last row containing data with

```
Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need VBA for something that so easy to do by hand ?
Also, why not putting the Total at the TOP of the columns, abve the titles, where you won't have to move them, and where they can stay visible at all times, provided tah you freeze the first 2 rows ??
Anyway, here's a solution:

```
With Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
   .Formula = "=Row()-1" 'assuming you have 1 row of title
End With
```